# Stopping ec2 to scale-down before it completes the process running on it

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

We have an application which runs on ec2 instances that we use as docker host in ecs cluster. There are multiple tasks running on each ec2. Each task picks up one message from SQS and process some event(which convert data from one format to other and upload it to a file system), which may take from few seconds to 12-15hours depending on the size of the data it contains. Once an event processing is  completed task is stopped and for new message(event) new task is created.  Whenever there are huge number of messages in SQS we are scaling-up the instances to process the messages (to avoid wait time). When (number of messages) < (number of running tasks) for certain duration then we need to scale-down i.e. we need to terminate ec2 instances.

For ec2 scale-down we need to make sure there is no task running i.e. container is not processing any event on it. There is no way to found out which ec2 are free(not processing any event) so we marked container to DRAINING state and then TERMINATING ec2. But while we mark any container to draining state, task running  on it, are stopped(hence event processing is killed in between and data is lost). Is there any why we can complete the process before tasks are stopped or anyone can suggest better approach.